# Modifying a val in Scala. Why I can do that?

Tags: scala, variables

As far as I know, a `val` in Scala is an inmutable value. So... Why can I modify a JFrame and a JLabel like that if they are declared as a `val`?

```
package view

import javax.swing.JFrame
import javax.swing.JLabel
import java.awt.BorderLayout

object Hello {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(hello)
    val frame = new JFrame
    val label = new JLabel()

    // here I am modifying val's!
    label setText ("hello")

    frame setSize (500, 500)
    frame getContentPane () setLayout (new BorderLayout)
    frame add (label, BorderLayout CENTER)
    frame setVisible (true)
    frame setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not re-assigning the references to label or frame.  That is what is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

`val value = new MyClass` means you can't bind a new reference to `value`:

```
value = new MyClass // is illegal
value.changeObjectState  // is legal
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change the object `frame` is referencing to. But you can't change the reference itself.
Try to do this:

```
val frame = new JFrame()
frame = new JFrame()
```

Answer (score 1):

`val` only prevents you from assigning a new object to the variable; you can still modify the state of the object referred to by a `val`.

Answer (score 1):

You r confusing between constant value - `val` and immutable objects. In your code, `JFrame` and `JLabel` are perfectly mutable cause they have getters and setters which mutating the internal state of the objects. But a `val` value means that you can't assign another object reference.